# Is there something similar to try_retain()?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to apply `FnMut(&mut V) -> Result<bool>` for collection elements and if result is:

- `Ok(false)` -- remove element and continue
- `Ok(true)` -- leave element in collection and continue
- `Err(_)` -- stop and return the error

Basically, how to code a `try_retain()`, an equivalent of [this C++ code](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAzBqkAA6oCoRODB7evnrJqY4CQSHhLFEx8baY9vkMQgRMxASZPn5cFVXptfUEhWGR0XoKdQ1N2a2DXT3FpRIAlLaoXsTI7BzmscHI3lgA1CaxbixMiXvYJhoAgmsbW5i7%2B8iD%2BKgnZ5cXXqlG28xsColMy22jz2Vgur0GxC8Dm2Ql2AHZQedtsjtgB6VHbAB02NeJjhABEQbiLujtnJEugmARMApdgA2DQKEwM7YQQzoba5VIRWgATyBqDY20wqmpxGYtCBdWpc22xEwBEWDFpBEhtzwVHpjOZGm2eFpDFQ21oAmA0W%2BmEwWHQr1JBAQxFQAHdaQJhcRHcRXhFUJ5thF6hAhOY6UCZkSwRcAG6oPAc/ioCCPEAgQ7HfbBAikGEvMyhlgzeGIlHbVW814lvHFkso/jENleIh6gh3fHbFiYqLAYIQWWEAD6rlb7cxrl7IOb2zAYD2bYHrgnharFZrq41rID9cIAFoTko0Ax0DNwxdV2eUR3okwlBBCNZrOHYtXz8jKkoVy%2Ba/fLHenx%2BvwS/54oSp4oqIBDIAgEDYpiJ5Iiiy6gauiTEJmVAQOYZgBnQVrCvUfImAArG4DCYY%2Bz41vajpOhG8HIsBuKARcHBzLQnCEbwfgcFopCoJwbjfhYAqLICaw8KQBCaCxcwIJgTBYDEvakAA1iAkh0pidKSAAnBokhwmY2mxLEhFwtp0hsRwki8CwIB0mYmJwrEXB5k5kiERoHkABzaYRpBcTxfEcLwCggAkkncSxpBwLAMCICggqJDhZAUBAaAsEl9AxMAXAaGYpBYFGeDLAAangmBOgA8okjCcOJNC0GKoUQBEUmkBEwT1LydW8OlbCCJVDB8m1WCHEY4iRQVeDyg4eBRjSbUipgyCNis4mZpUbW0HgETEF1HhYD1EmobZ3BRVQBjAAoZUVdVtVnTIggiGI7BSI98hKGobW6PlBhGCggn6DtoWQHMqCJNUoUcNulWxNs24AOpiJK27ArE%2BKmJY1hcHC8MQw6cnoCFlTLdULiHiMLSkIEwS9CU/StLkaQCJTOQpMzDCTH0MRjCTs0CJ0wyeM0Ax89UgvdLTUwM7YQyNMLoyyxMUvc7M8wia9rHsZxbVBdsqheXS25adswDIMg2y5ZiZisrghAkLsZjOTMvARVox6kLJ8n9EpqlmHCmKmXmZhcLEkheWZBl%2BZZ1mkLZcIaJiUixF5Xnh9pZgaIbxn%2BbrnAhWFElSXMMXxQsBCJI25AuPgRCoegej8E9ojiG9TcfSo6iTT9pBOntiQ9VrHAcbnk1BZVjaVy2qCagbRsm2bFtWzbEAeBlyWO7EZgu0XkUe17CmUEPse2YZmJeYRdJcFwhG5WZod0nC0gBbwQUF%2BFxdzH7AeSMnKdaRoLOGdw76E4LEHWY98673dtFOKpcIBIHSplaI1c0qJWSigWg/YQhOn7FpAqmAiqlXKlVGqXF6p0CapQVqk0OrMGIN1B6fVGAEEGsNSao1DDAAmjxfAM1HDzShjxJaK1qRHQ2pZHi21dr7QwGtV2J1B58EutdEhd1yG8Hbs9Vu0h26KE7t9PQf1jCA2kSDJS4NIacFRAjSQaJkyYysJYHGaJKqqDRNgAAEgoZAxN2jOAgK4VmrQaZFFVozdm1RglJEiekLm9MeZtFJh0OW0S7DJIFnLeJ0wxipIVlTcYDRskMzmAoBYSxNagOHhAwKnB9YmxYAoKMFsoxcG0knOxEAEYAElQjYELBAO2ddN5cB3m7aSntCY%2B2PjZEAHlR61OCrYQu4yS5wKQOXKeqCrT23ro3WQ2jXq6NkPor63c9B9yOEoyyI8X68U4BPCujZtgz3qXYxpzTtitPaVIVkPS%2BkDLXsg4gIyxmf0md7RSX8QBmC8oHMOsK4ReS4HSIOEcvJVJPnMhIdy37LI/nvaFZhCKYiMnSK%2BkgNDksIoRWFJkqngIWa/KBqyh5mFmblROgDuU8p5a0XFLLwXzWIKkZwkggA%3D%3D%3D):

```
struct S {
    // ...
};

// Updates `s` (and possibly some external state), returns true if `s` is no longer needed
// throws on error
bool bar(S& s);

void foo(std::map<int, S>& m) {
    try
    {
        for(auto it = m.begin(), it_end = m.end(); it != it_end; ) {
            if (bar(it->second))
                m.erase(it++);
            else
                ++it;
        }
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        printf("bailed early\n");
        throw;
    }
}
```

For some reason I keep running into this pattern and I can't figure out how to do it in Rust without traversing collection twice or using additional memory...

Comment: you could implement it yourself as a default method in a trait and then implement your trait for all `T: Iterator`, just like itertools does it: [`impl<T: ?Sized> Itertools for T where T: Iterator { }`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/src/itertools/lib.rs.html#3662)

Comment: @hellow note that `retain` is not an `Iterator` method (nor is it part of any trait). It's just a method that's implemented for most containers.

Comment: [Either](https://docs.rs/either/latest/either/) should help you with your problem.

Comment: @Kaplan can you elaborate?

Comment: Because the return value depends directly on the existence of items to be removed, `either` has no advantage. My [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74859847/is-there-something-similar-to-try-retain/74874201#74874201) has a time penalty because the items to be removed must be saved first. But it uses no external crates nor unsafe code.

Answer (score 1):

This won't short-circuit, but you can do it by storing the global result in a mutable variable that's updated by the closure you pass to `retain`. Something like this:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn try_retain<K, V, E, F>(m: &mut HashMap<K, V>, mut f: F) -> Result<(), E>
where
    F: FnMut(&K, &mut V) -> Result<bool, E>,
{
    let mut result = Ok(());
    m.retain(|k, v| match f(k, v) {
        Ok(b) => b,
        Err(e) => {
            result = Err(e);
            true
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ea57de85404b12b5cc9fbb9db0b6b186)

Comment: I thought about smth like this (only I'd stop calling `f(k,v)` after `result` is set to `Err(e)`) -- it is still not ideal as you'll end up unnecessarily completing iteration. :-/

Comment: I wonder if short-circuiting can be implemented via `panic`? (i.e. use `panic` similarly to C++ `throw`)

Comment: @C.M. you should never rely on any panicking behavior, as it is platform-dependent and can even be easily changed in the Cargo.toml file.

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine with switching to `hashbrown::HashMap` (which is what `std::collections::HashMap` uses as it's inner implementation), you could copy the implementation of `fn retain` and slightly change it to use the `?` operator to return the first error:

```rust
fn try_retain<K, V, E, F>(m: &mut hashbrown::HashMap<K, V>, mut f: F) -> Result<(), E>
where
    F: FnMut(&K, &mut V) -> Result<bool, E>,
{
    let mut raw_table = m.raw_table();

    // Here we only use `iter` as a temporary, preventing use-after-free
    unsafe {
        for item in raw_table.iter() {
            let &mut (ref key, ref mut value) = item.as_mut();
            if !f(key, value)? {
                raw_table.erase(item);
            }
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

This requires `hashbrown`'s `raw` feature to be enabled, so you can access the underlying raw table.

This stops at the first error, and the elements are visited in a random order, so it's non-deterministic which elements are removed if an error occurs.

Comment: That is a pretty cool hashmap implementation, I've never heard about it. And it's API permits (albeit unsafe) container modification while iterating (C++-style). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We could use `try_for_each` and remember the keys to remove *(not to retain)* till the end of the iteration because of the borrow checker:

```
fn try_retain(
    map: &mut HashMap<i32, i32>,
    to_retain: fn(k: i32, v: i32) -> bool,
) -> Result<bool, String> {
    let mut to_remove: Vec<i32> = vec![];
    map.iter().try_for_each(|(k, v)| {
        if has_error() {
            return Err("bailed early".to_string());
        }
        if !to_retain(*k, *v) {
            to_remove.push(*k);
        }
        Ok::<_, String>(())
    })?;  // short-circuiting
    if to_remove.is_empty() {
        Ok(true)
    } else {
        (*map).retain(|&k, _| !to_remove.contains(&k));
        Ok(false)
    }
}
```

The return value results from whether there are keys to remove.
Can short-circuiting.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4abd985b35efe4d04ead00ce74f29a18)

---

If the extra space for the *to-remove-items* is still too much, here is an unstable solution with `drain_filter`:

```
fn try_retain(
    map: &mut HashMap<i32, i32>,
    to_retain: fn(k: i32, v: i32) -> bool,
) -> bool {
    let mut rslt = true;
    map.drain_filter(|k, v| {
        if !to_retain(*k, *v) {
            rslt = false;
            true
        } else {
            false
        }
    });
    rslt
}
```

Short-circuiting is only possible through `panic`.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b3f152ec1022b27706da20a8d6e2b21f)

Comment: Short-circuits, but requires iterating over the map twice and extra allocations.

Comment: yeah... this is what I meant by "can't do it without using extra memory"

Comment: I had gotten the *traversing-twice-thing* as the usual functional `…collect::HashMap<_, _>()` solution. But as you didn't want any memory allocation either, the `drain_filter` solution should make you happier.